# Examples of pathology of p-adic étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I've often heard p-adic étale cohomology described as "pathological". Can you give some explicit computations showing which expectations it defies?

Comment: You could consult Ogus *Cohomology of the infinitesimal site*, which shows that when $X$ is a proper $k$-scheme where $k$ is a perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebra, then the étale cohomology of $X$ coincides with the "unit root part" of the crystalline cohomology.

Comment: I think the most classical example is etale cohomology of chararacteristic p abelian variety, which fails to see the inseparable part of its p-torsion. Perhaps not a "pathology" per se but this shows it is unsuitable for treating Weil conjectures, for instance (it is "too small")

Comment: Wojowo is right. In particular, I would start with an elliptic curve. $H^1(E, \mathbb Z_p)$ is $\mathbb Z_p$ if $E$ is ordinary and $0$ if $E$ is supersingular.

Comment: (but we expect it to be $\mathbb Z_p^2$ in this setting if we want it to mimic $\ell$-adic étale cohomology, singular cohomology, characteristic zero de Rham cohomology, ...)